# Django DecimalField form field errors not shown in template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a silly problem. I have a decimal field with 1 decimal place allowed. I need to manually iterate over the form fields in the template and render them. If in the template I set the input to type="text" and enter a number with two decimal places in the form the error message ("Ensure that there are no more than 1 decimal place.") is displayed in the template. However, when I set the input to type="number" and step="0.1", then the error is not displayed in the template. I can just set it as text, but that means users can enter any characters. I prefer not to do that and have it as a type="number" so that they can only enter digits.

Any help would be appreciated.

Minimal code:

```
# forms.py
class TimeForm(forms.Form):
    time = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1, label = 'Time')

# template
<form method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<div>
 <input type="number" step="0.1" class="form-control {% if form.time.errors %} is-invalid {% endif %}" 
  name="{{form.time.name}}" id="{{ form.time.id_for_label }}"
  {% if form.time.value %} value="{{form.time.value}}" {% else %} placeholder="Total Time" {% endif %}>
  {% if form.time.errors %}
    {% for error in form.time.errors %}
      <span class="invalid-feedback">{{error}}</span>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I encountered another similar problem where my form was not rendering the errors the way I wanted them to be rendered. I wanted to give the input field a red border and have the error displayed beneath it like bootstrap. But I was getting a pop-up inside of the input field. This was the browser doing some validation. The solution was to add novalidate attribute to the form tag.

```
<form novalidate method="POST">
```